# create square on google map determine if user is within that square

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Is it possible to create a square in google maps and then determine if that user is within that square using gps? I am asking this because I created an app that tracks a users location adn tracks their movement but I only want it to track movement if the user is within that square. Any guidance at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.html

Comment: this exact question was posted only a few hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255985/create-a-square-in-google-maps-so-when-someone-enters-the-square-an-action-is-ex are you and this other person friends or something